# undefined method `copy' for File:Class

Tags: ruby-1.9.2

I've just upgraded a project to Ruby 1.9.2 and the following line crashes the app with 'undefined method `copy' for File:Class'

```
File.copy(animage.image.path(:export), destfile)
```

I have the following libraries loaded in this module

```
require 'zip/zipfilesystem'
require 'iconv'
require 'net/ftp'
require 'fileutils'
```

Comment: shouldn't it be File.cp? or rather FileUtils.cp

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should actually be `FileUtils.copy` or `FileUtils.cp`. I wonder how your old project worked with just File.copy, as File doesn't have that method.

refer here: http://santoro.tk/mirror/ruby-core/classes/FileUtils.html#M004325

Answer (score 3):

You were probably using [ftools](http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/ftools/rdoc/index.html) in 1.8:

> ftools adds several (class, not instance) methods to the File class, for copying, moving, deleting, installing, and comparing files, as well as creating a directory path. See the File class for details.

ftools was replaced by fileutils in 1.9, about the 6th element in this [list of standard library changes in 1.9](http://pragdave.blogs.pragprog.com/pragdave/2008/04/ruby-19-standar.html) from Dave Thomas